How to implement mAP in Kaggle?
My goal is to try and implement Mean Average Precision from a given notebook (https://www.kaggle.com/code/balraj98/yolo-v5-car-object-detection/notebook#). The process is still new to me, and it would be useful if someone gives directions on how to do it.
Any tips on how to achieve this?
I have seen this notebook (https://www.kaggle.com/code/vencerlanz09/ships-object-detection-using-yolov8#Evaluation) which explains mAP, but cannot run it - this path does not exist.
model = YOLO('/kaggle/working/runs/detect/train/weights/best.pt').


In this notebook the best.pt file is created as a result of the Model Training step. After finishing it (it will take time, about an hour) the output will show Results saved to runs/detect/train message, and then you can proceed with the rest of the script. Change the pre-trained model in the line model = YOLO('yolov8x.pt') to yolov8n.pt if you want faster training. Note that in the training process step of this notebook, you will be asked to input your wandb API key (https://wandb.ai/site), if you don't, the training will never start, and the best.pt model file will never be created.
